# change Qt GUI by Qt tcp socket?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

i have a server and client.i am going to change the handle of my clock to new value that will send by client to server.i added the source code below.
***my problem*** is when client connect to server after client send data to server to change the handle of clock to new data. ***the gui that created in Server::startRead() method appear and disappear automatically***. what is wrong with my code please.

server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class Server: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

   QString buf;
  Server(QObject * parent = 0);
  ~Server();
public slots:
  void acceptConnection();
  void startRead();
  QString getinfo();

private:
  QTcpServer server;
  QTcpSocket* client;
};


#endif // SERVER_H
```

server.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include "server.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include "qlabel.h"
#include <QtGui>
Server::Server(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{

connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
    this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));


  server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234);
  qDebug() <<  "connected";
}

Server::~Server()
{
  server.close();
}

void Server::acceptConnection()
{

  qDebug()<<"accept connection";
  client = server.nextPendingConnection();
  client->write("Hello client\r\n");

  connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
    this, SLOT(startRead()));

}

void Server::startRead()
{

    client->waitForReadyRead(3000);
    QString buf=client->readAll();

    qDebug() << buf;

    static const QPoint minuteHand[3] = {
        QPoint(7, 8),
        QPoint(-7, 8),
        QPoint(0, -40)
    };
     int side = qMin(200, 200);
    QColor minuteColor(60, 60, 0);
    QPixmap pixmap( 200, 200 );
    pixmap.fill( Qt::red );
    QPainter painter( &pixmap );
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.translate(200 / 2, 200 / 2);
    painter.scale(side / 200.0, side / 200.0);

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        painter.drawLine(88, 0, 96, 0);
        painter.rotate(30.0);
    }
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(minuteColor);

    painter.save();
    painter.rotate(240);
    painter.drawConvexPolygon(minuteHand, 3);
    painter.restore();

    painter.setPen(minuteColor);

    for (int j = 0; j < 60; ++j) {
        if ((j % 5) != 0)
            painter.drawLine(92, 0, 96, 0);
        painter.rotate(6.0);
    }

    QLabel l;
    l.setPixmap(pixmap);
    l.show();

}
QString Server::getinfo()
{

 qDebug()<< buf;
    return buf;

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "server.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "analogclock.h"
#include "qlabel.h"
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

Server s;



    return a.exec();
}
```

application output

```
Starting C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0_1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-NHAJA-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\NHAJA.exe...
connected
accept connection
"11"
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0_1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-NHAJA-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\NHAJA.exe exited with code 0
```

I really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you isolate the code you think may be the problem?  It seems that you have a very direct question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables created in the functions only exist while the function is called, so when the function is finished executing the variables are eliminated, and in your case the QLabel is eliminated.

A possible solution is to create `QLabel` as a member of the class:

**server.h**

```
private:
    QLabel *label;
```

**server.cpp**

```
Server::Server(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    [...]
    qDebug() <<  "connected";
    label = new QLabel;
}

void Server::startRead()
{
    [...]
    for (int j = 0; j < 60; ++j) {
        if ((j % 5) != 0)
            painter.drawLine(92, 0, 96, 0);
        painter.rotate(6.0);
    }

    label->setPixmap(pixmap);
    label->show();

}
```